# Do not allow width to shrink

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Edited: added fiddle and code samples

I've got many columns which occupy width which is calculated dynamically, based on the child content width. But when I use search input for filtering results in specific column, width jumps, because children divs become hidden and hence they do not need their width anymore.

How can I prevent this from happening? I cannot use fixed width or min-width, because every column is different - they can and should be very wide or very tiny.

https://jsfiddle.net/wuvm6f1y/11/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <span>Type 'bla' and see how first column shrinks</span><br>
  <input type="text" v-model="searchWord" @input="searchRows">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="row" v-for="(row) in rows1" v-show="row.visible">{{row.value}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="row" v-for="(row) in rows2">{{row}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

Vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    searchWord: "",
    rows1: [{
        value: "long long long long long row",
        visible: true
      },
      {
        value: "blablabla",
        visible: true
      }
    ],
    rows2: ["short row", "blabla"],
  },
  methods: {
    searchRows: function() {
      this.rows1.forEach((row) => {
        row.visible = true
        if (!row.value.match(this.searchWord)) {
          row.visible = false
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Please add the code you've used to create this so we can replicate the problem and look for a fix. Right now we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by properly using using table tags, with styles as described here https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/column-widths-to-auto-adjust-for-text/107326